# How to check an alias for a cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to check an alias for a cmdlet. How could I verify this through a command?

I have been trying this way:

```
Get-Command -CommandType alias | Where-Object {$ _. Name-like "Copy-Item"}
```

Result:

[image: There was a problem loading this image.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Get-Alias -Definition Copy-Item
```

`Get-Help` explains the use of `-Definition`:

> Specifies an array of aliases for the specified item.
>   Enter the name of a cmdlet, function, script, file, or executable
>   file.

Comment: `gal -d copy-item` if you are like me, too lazy to write this whole text

Comment: And to get the alias of an alias, `gal gal`

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to match on `Name`, you want to match on `Definition`:

```
Get-Command -CommandType Alias | Where-Object {$_.Definition -like "Copy-Item"}
```

You can often find a lot of useful information by piping the output of a command to `Get-Member`.

Answer (score 1):

You already have your answer, but if you ever want to check for all aliases on a system, for cmdlet/function or even a parameters of said same, here is a way to do it.

```
# Get all named aliases 
Get-Alias | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available aliases'

# Get cmdlet / function parameter aliases
(Get-Command Get-Process).Parameters.Values | 
where aliases | 
select Name, Aliases | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Alias results for a given cmdlet or function.'
```